After Ugrading Ubuntu 23.10 to 24.04, ssh-add is broken
This was working before the upgrade. Now I see the following error:
$ ssh-add -l
error fetching identities: Invalid key length

My SSH version:
ssh -V
OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13, OpenSSL 3.0.13 30 Jan 2024

When running strace I see the following:
getrandom("\x5e\xe1\x4e\x2e\x42\xfe\x7a\x68\xcb\xec\xb1\xc9\x06\xd9\x44\x20\xa4\xd4\xa5\xcd\x30\x05\x26\xb1\x01\x9c\xb8\x34\xee\x05\x4e\x4f"...,
48, 0) = 48
getrandom("\x92\x40\xe5\x10\xa4\xda\xfb\xe2\x89\xe4\x91\xc2\x91\xe4\xa0\x56\x50\xe0\xa7\x47\xf5\xc3\x3f\xf4\x1e\xb3\x10\x66\x53\x48\xd7\x98"...,
48, 0) = 48
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 3
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_UNIX,
sun_path="/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh"}, 110) = 0
write(3, "\0\0\0\1", 4)                 = 4
write(3, "\v", 1)                       = 1
read(3, "\0\0\1u", 4)                   = 4
read(3,
"\f\0\0\0\1\0\0\1\27\0\0\0\7ssh-rsa\0\0\1\1\0\345\211=gs\345\322"...,
373) = 373
write(2, "error fetching identities: Inval"..., 46error fetching
identities: Invalid key length
) = 46
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++

So it appears it is trying to read something from gpg-agent, which is causing this problem. How can I know what that is?
EDIT
I can't post ls -l ~/.ssh as that contains some proprietary content I can't post here, but it is the same content as before the upgrade, which was working.
$SSH_AUTH_SOCK is /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh which is what I expect.
$SSH_AGENT_PID is not set. Is it supposed to be?
This is time sensitive, so I had to reinstall Ubuntu 23.10, which is working. I no longer have access to an affected system to further debug.
Oddly though, on another system I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.04 (not an upgrade path) and that also works correctly.
So I'm guessing something is wrong with the upgrade path.

Can you post the output of ls -l ~/.ssh?

Presumably it thinks that /run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh is an ssh-agent socket file - what do echo "SSH_AUTH_SOCK" and ps -fp "$SSH_AGENT_PID" tell you?

It seems that you have a conflict between ssh-agent user service and gpg-agent-ssh. You should disable gpg-agent-ssh and reboot :
 sudo systemctl --global disable gpg-agent-ssh.socket


This worked for me with different symptoms: I could add keys with ssh-add but they were not used.
